# Return value from paypal

Tags: paypal

I'm tracking a conversion for a site which allows donations with paypal. The user doesn't define on our page what he/she is going to donate. I've set the auto return on inside the paypal acc. My question is ( and this is quite stupid that I can't find this anywhere ) How do i read-out the donated amount after paypal has redirected to my thank you page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When donate transaction will complete successfully, PayPal will return to merchant website with below response parameter:

```
tx=TRANSACTION_ID /*TRANSACTION ID*/
st=Completed /*Transaction Status*/
amt=DONATE_AMT /*Donor Entered amount*/
```

So, You can easily track donate amount using PayPal response.

Comment: Will this be in the URL or in a cookie?

Comment: It will be in URL. 
If you are using PHP, You can use $_GET['amt'] to read amount parameter value